# Magnetic vortex in magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, charge, vortex

I was doing some physics problems and randomly came upon a seemingly very intelligent but very rude individual.

His video in question was about magnetism and that there is a vortex and counter-vortex at both ends of a magnet.

This is the video: https://youtu.be/Sn2mAnoQmQk

(The demonstration happens at around the 5min mark).

What he showed was interesting enough for me to overlook the rudeness, and looking into him, he seemed to not be just an outright “quack”, so it stayed in my mind.

The tone seems like what he’s showing is apparently counter to what modern physics models predict, or something.

The more I think about it and imagine the magnet’s magnetic field, the more I’m convinced its perfectly sufficient for explaining what you see in the video.

Any help with trying to unpack this (and figuring out what he’s even claiming!) would be very appreciated, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't blame you at all for your confusion. It seems that he's attempting to scientifically demonstrate or argue something on the basis of electromagnetism, but his assertion is rather unprofessional; I've read many scientific research papers, and not once have I encountered one that appeared so paranoid about people accusing the author of "trickery"! The video's descriptions and comments don't really elaborate on his point either, unfortunately.

Anyways, onto the actual argument he's making...assuming he is actually making one..? It's pretty well-known and understood why magnets have that sort of effect on older TV screens. Old television monitors worked because of cathode ray tubes, which created the picture we see on a TV screen using beams of electrons (in the video, this guy explicitly mentions that he's using an older TV). The presence of a magnet nearby will interfere with the electron's movements. If you grew up being warned not to put magnets close to the TV, this is generally the reason why.

So yeah, I'm not quite sure what he's claiming to have proven here. The only thing he says is that this is a demonstration of some sort of "magnetic vortex", but I believe he's misusing the word. A quick Wikipedia search reveals that the word "vortex" in physics primarily refers to a phenomenon in fluid mechanics, completely irrelevant to what Theoria Apophasis (TA) is talking about. It would help if TA defined "vortex" in his video, or explained what he means specifically when he uses the word, but because he doesn't, his video ends up feeling rather incomplete.

I think he's falling into the common misunderstanding that "vortex" can be used to refer to just any old shape that happens to resemble a "swirl" pattern, but once again, the imagery in the video is not a new discovery.

It might be worth looking into his older videos (to see if more info is buried in his uploads), or simply ask him for a technical explanation of what he's talking about. ...Considering his apparent attitude (and his clear resistance to criticism, evident on his more popular uploads), I'm not sure how well that will go, but I digress.